# Cut Paste shortcuts issue

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I hope to get some help here. I really don't know how to tackle this issue that I'm experiencing in the last days.

In the last few days, `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+x` work randomly in every application.
For example, if I want to copy some string in gedit, I need to press `ctrl+c` many times to actually copy it in the clipboard.
The "cut" shortcut has basically become useless instead. In fact, it always correctly deletes the text, but it doesn't copy that to the clipboard. The result is that the text disappear, but I can't paste it.

I have this issue also when I make a screenshot and put it in the clipboard. :(

As far as I know, I haven't done anything unusual in the last days that might have caused this issue.

I use Fedora 31, gnome-shell 3.34.1.

Can you please give me some help, at least, on how to start debugging this issue? It's a real pain.

Comment: Have you tried to use some software like `showkey` to test the `CTRL` key? Maybe it has some bad contact?

Comment: Yes, I did. Both `c` and `ctrl` work fine. In fact, I use many shortcuts, and the `ctrl` never fails. The same for the letter `c`.
I also checked with a clipboard gnome extension: text is copied in that clipboard, but still I can't paste it.

Comment: I suspect it's due to a gnome extension indeed...